# Weird values in GloVe embeddings causing error importing

Tags: stanford-nlp, valueerror, word-embedding

I'm trying to load GloVe embedding data, and when just printing out the words and their corresponding embeddings I get an anomaly. With the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
filename = "glove.840B.300d.txt"

embeddings_dict = {}

with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = line.split()
        word = values[0]
        try:
            vector = np.asarray(values[1:], "float32")
        except ValueError:
            print('Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values): ', values[:5])
            print('\n')
            pass
        embeddings_dict[word] = vector
```

Here is a snippet where the output runs into problems:

```
Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['.', '.', '.', '-0.1573', '-0.29517']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['at', 'name@domain.com', '0.0061218', '0.39595', '-0.22079']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['to', 'name@domain.com', '0.33865', '0.12698', '-0.16885']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['.', '.', '0.035974', '-0.024421', '0.71402']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['.', '.', '.', '.', '0.033459']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['email', 'name@domain.com', '0.33529', '0.32949', '0.2646']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['or', 'name@domain.com', '0.48374', '0.49669', '-0.25089']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['contact', 'name@domain.com', '0.016426', '0.13728', '0.18781']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['Email', 'name@domain.com', '0.37344', '0.024573', '-0.12583']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['on', 'name@domain.com', '0.037295', '-0.15381', '-0.045189']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['At', 'Killerseats.com', '-0.13854', '-0.01706', '-0.13651']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['by', 'name@domain.com', '0.6882', '-0.36436', '0.62079']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['in', 'mylot.com', '-0.18148', '0.47096', '0.32916']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['emailing', 'name@domain.com', '0.39173', '-0.39132', '-0.4266']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['Contact', 'name@domain.com', '0.14933', '-0.28605', '0.3444']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['at', 'name@domain.com', '0.44321', '-0.40005', '-0.20065']


Weird value detected with vector (showing first few values):  ['•', 'name@domain.com', '-0.13288', '-0.31383', '-0.032356']
```

What is going on with these lines? Have I imported GloVe incorrectly? Should I just ignore these? I don't really know what to do with these.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, pretty sure it has to do with the version of Glove that you have downloaded. In my case, the words with these errors were usually removed by using a stop word dict.

Try downloading a different version from https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/
or you can either remove the words with these embeddings from your vocab and features or replace the string with a default number on your own.